# get value from $.postJSON or wait for it to finish

Tags: jquery, json, post

I am making a simple JSON post to the server and I retrieve just on boolean. The problem is that this json call is inside another function which needs to return that boolean as well.

I have two solutions here

1. Somehow return data from JSON return function and then return it again from wrapper function (the code that I have here doesn't work, I can't figure out how to return data from "function(){} inside $.postJSON:

   ```
       function testZipCode(zipcode, state) {
       var s;
       $.postJSON("/Cart/ZipTest",
           {
               state: state,
               zipCode: zipcode
           }, function (data) {
               if (!data.ok) {
                   s = false;
               }
               s = true;
           });
           return s;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Wait for POST to finish and then return the result like this: (the error I get here is that I call return before POST is finished, thus responseText is null. Can anyone please help?

   ```
    var result = $.postJSON("/Cart/ZipTest",
    {
               state: state,
               zipCode: zipcode
           }, function (data) {
               if (!data.ok) {
                   //do something
               }
           });
           return $.parseJSON(result.responseText).ok;
   ```

Comment: Did you create a method called `jQuery.postJSON`? jQuery doesn't come with one built-in. your return `$.parseJSON(...)` will happen before the responsetext has a value, asynchronous code shouldn't be written that way.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Yes I do have .postJSON. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the ajax call as a deffered object and do something in the callback function:

```
function someOtherFunction() {
    testZipCode('90102', 'FL').done(function(data) {
        if (!data.ok) something = false;
    });

}

function testZipCode(zipcode, state) {
    return $.getJSON("/Cart/ZipTest", {state: state, zipCode: zipcode} );
}​
```

Comment: can I use something inside someOtherFunction() after I exit from testZipCode?

Comment: Only inside the callback or by calling `done()`, `always()` etc. on the deffered object again somewhere else in the code by using a variable for the returned object, as that is how asynchronous ajax calls work.

Comment: My objective here is to exit from someOtherfunction() if the result from ZipTest.ok == false; If I can't use `something` outside of done() then I won't be able to do it right?

Comment: Well, sure you can. But if you're doing something that relies on data received from an ajax call, you'll have to wait until that data is returned, there is no other option, and since the call is asynchronous you'll have to use a callback function of some sorts to execute the code when the data is actually available. In other words you'll have to check the data and either return from the function or do whatever it is you intend to do inside the callback function, otherwise the data from the ajax call is'nt available yet.

Comment: I just used synchronous ajax call for this. Thanks for help!

Comment: That's one way to go, and in some cases it's ok, but it's generally not recommended as it locks the browser.

Comment: In this case, it doesn't matter because I lock the browser anyway for "loading" purposes, and the call is pretty fast anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this ..

```
 {
            state: state,
            zipCode: zipcode
        }, function (data, count) {
            if (!data.ok) {
               getTheData(data); //do something
            }
        });


           return $.parseJSON(result.responseText).ok;

         function getTheData(data)
{
//do things with data here
}
```